# How to lower window so its behind all others - just like mouse middle button

Tags: command-line, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

I am looking for the keyboard equivalent to pressing mouse middle roller-button while cursor is at window top title bar.  This lowers that window so its behind all other windows.

Comment: Lower the frontmost (active) window or, like the "real" button, any window under the cursor? The first one is easy, the last one much more complex...

Comment: I will take (active) however the mouse technique works for any window, not necessarily the active one

Comment: I know, but it will probably be hard coded and not available as a separate command :)

Comment: In Openbox (not the default wm in Ubuntu), you can set a keybind for "focustobottom": http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#FocusToBottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### A shamlessly dirty solution

To achieve a command that does what you want turns out to be more complicated than it seems at first sight. The issue is to lower the window and maintain the window order (z-wise) at the same time, which seems nearly impossible. Both `xdotool` and `wmctrl` provide commands to *raise* a window, but not to *lower* a window.

The solution below is a dirty hack/workaround, but it works nicely and reliably nevertheless. It uses both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`, which are not on your system by default.

Although the script is run by a keyboard shortcut, it actually does exactly the same as when you middle-click on the top of your window. What it does:

- It looks up the active window (using `xprop -root`)
- Looks up if the window is a "normal" window (unlike e.g. your desktop, which is also listed in `wmctrl -lG` as a window)
- If so, it calculates the position of the top of the window, moves the mouse to the calculated position, simulates middle- click and moves the mouse back to where you left it.

This all happens in a split second, so you won't even notice the mouse moving and moving back. The only thing you notice is the window sent to back, which is exactly what you want.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

# find the frontmost window
active = [l for l in subprocess.check_output(["xprop", "-root"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines() \
          if "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)" in l][0].split("#")[-1].strip()
# convert the window-id from xprop- format to wmctrl- format
w_id = active[:2] + str((10-len(active))*"0")+active[2:]
# if the window is a "normal" window, find the window geometry in wmctrl -lG,
# move the mouse to the top of the window and click the middle button
if "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL" in subprocess.check_output(["xprop", "-id", w_id]).decode("utf-8"):
    match = [l for l in subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lG"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines() if w_id in l][0].split()[2:6]
    current_mousepos = subprocess.check_output(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).decode("utf-8").split()
    coords = ([s.replace("x:", "") for s in current_mousepos if s.startswith("x:")][0],
              [s.replace("y:", "") for s in current_mousepos if s.startswith("y:")][0])
    top_x = str(int(int(match[0])+(int(match[2])/2))); top_y = str(int(match[1]) -10)
    # The time.sleep(0.3) possibly needs to be optimized (longer sleep = safer); the 0.3 works fine on my system when used from a keyboard shortcut (which turns out to make a difference...)
    subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "mousemove", "--sync", top_x, top_y]); time.sleep(0.3)
    # move the mouse back to its original position
    subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "click", "2"]); time.sleep(0.05)
    subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "mousemove", coords[0], coords[1]])
```

#### How to use

1. Install both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl
   ```
2. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `sendtoback.py`
3. Test- run the script by opening a terminal, run the command in it:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/sendtoback.py
   ```

   The window should be sent to the background, exactly like you were used to when middle-clicked.
4. If all works fine, Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/sendtoback.py
   ```

   to a key shortcut of your choice.

#### Note

In some cases (especially on slower systems), the sleep time in the line:

```
subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "mousemove", "--sync", top_x, top_y]); time.sleep(0.3)
```

needs to be increased. On faster systems, it could be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome provides keybindings via `gnome-keybinding-properties` in Gnome 2, and via `gnome-control-center keyboard` in Gnome 3.

In Gnome 2, the default active keybinding that comes close to what you want is

> Raise window if it's covered by another window, otherwise lower it

using a shortcut of <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

---

*Edit:* I'm using `mate` now, which is a fork of Gnome 2, and using the command line gives me either "Command not found" for gnome-keybinding-properties, or a core dump for gnome-control-center.

But using the UI, the key binding are accessible under `System`->`Control Center`->`Hardware`->`Keyboard Shortcuts`.  It's easiest to collapse the `Sound`, `Desktop`, and `Accessibility` sections, which leaves `Window Management`.  *"Raise window if it's covered by another window, otherwise lower it"* is in about the middle of the section, and, in Mate, is disabled.

Comment: i dont seem to see that keyboard section there though

Comment: @FantomX1 - I'm not exactly sure where your "there" is, but I've updated my answer, and may have clarified things a bit for you.